# Consider the following LP. Apply surplus variables & initial tableau. Then use revised simplex method to obtain the tableau for basic variables

Tags: linear-programming

Consider this LP problem.

\begin{array}{cccll}
  \min        & Z= & 8x & +10y+25z           &        \\
  \text{s.t.} &    & 2x & \phantom{+10y}+ 2z & \ge 60 \\
              &    & 2x & +4y+5z             & \ge 70 \\
              &    &    & \phantom{+}3y+z    & \ge 27 \\
              &    &    & x,y,z              & \ge 0
\end{array}

I am confused as to why I have to do a revised simplex method here since the basic matrix has the identity form already.

But if I still apply the "rule" we learned in class to obtain the tableau, the tableau looks the same as our original tableau. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add surplus variables $s_1,s_2,s_3$ into the LP.

\begin{array}{rrrrrll}
  \min        & Z= & 8x & +10y & + 25z &             &      \\
  \text{s.t.} &    & 2x &      & + 2z  & - s_1       & = 60 \\
              &    & 2x & +4y  & + 5z  & - s_2       & = 70 \\
              &    &    & 3y   & + z   & - s_3       & = 27
\end{array}

$$x,y,z,s_1,s_2,s_3 \ge 0$$

Initially, we have $s_1,s_2,s_3$ as basic variables. Multiplying the
above three equations by $-1$ gives basic matrix $I_3$, but
$s_1,s_2,s_3$ are all negative, so it's a basic infeasible solution.
To find a BFS (basic feasible solution), you need the revised simplex
method.  In the intial simplex tableau below, we transform $\min Z$ to
$\max Z = -8x - 10y - 25z$ without changing any constraints.  (I note $x,y,z$ as $x_1,x_2,x_3$ respectively.)

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
    & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 &     \\ \hline
s_1 &  -2 &   0 &  -2 &   1 &   0 &   0 & -60 \\
s_2 &  -2 &  -4 &  -5 &   0 &   1 &   0 & -70 \\
s_3 &   0 &  -3 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & -27 \\ \hline
    &   8 &  10 &  25 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  0  \\
\end{array}

Using the two-phase method or the big-M method to find a basic
feasible solution is much slower than the dual simplex method.

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
    &  x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 &  s_1 &    s_2 &  s_3 &       \\       \hline
s_1 &   -2 &    0 &   -2 &    1 &      0 &    0 &   -60 \\
s_2 &   -2 & -4^* &   -5 &    0 &      1 &    0 &   -70 \\
s_3 &    0 &   -3 &   -1 &    0 &      0 &    1 &   -27 \\       \hline
    &    8 &   10 &   25 &    0 &      0 &    0 &     0 \\ \hline\hline
s_1 & -2^* &    0 &   -2 &    1 &      0 &    0 &   -60 \\
x_2 &  1/2 &    1 &  5/4 &    0 &   -1/4 &    0 &  35/2 \\
s_3 &  3/2 &    0 & 11/4 &    0 &   -3/4 &    1 &  51/2 \\       \hline
    &    3 &    0 & 25/2 &    0 &    5/2 &    0 &  -175 \\ \hline\hline
x_1 &    1 &    0 &    1 & -1/2 &      0 &    0 &    30 \\
x_2 &    0 &    1 &  3/4 &  1/4 &   -1/4 &    0 &   5/2 \\
s_3 &    0 &    0 &  5/4 &  3/4 & -3/4^* &    1 & -39/2 \\       \hline
    &    0 &    0 & 19/2 &  3/2 &    5/2 &    0 &  -265 \\ \hline\hline
x_1 &    1 &    0 &    1 & -1/2 &      0 &    0 &    30 \\
x_2 &    0 &    1 &  1/3 &    0 &      0 & -1/3 &     9 \\
s_2 &    0 &    0 & -5/3 &   -1 &      1 & -4/3 &    26 \\       \hline
    &    0 &    0 & 41/3 &    4 &      0 & 10/3 &  -330
\end{array}

Therefore, the optimal solution is $(x^*,y^*,z^*)=(30,9,0)$.