# Area of a surface by rotating the curve about the x-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, rotations

The curve $y=\sqrt{5-x}$ with $a=3$ and $b=5$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. Find the exact area of the surface obtained.

Comment: I found y'=(-1/(2sqrt(5-x))

Comment: Can you show us your steps [like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053889/290189) so that we know how you arrived at $$y'=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5-x}}.$$

Comment: (5-x)^(1/2) dx = (1/2(5-x)^(1/2))*-1

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem, we need to use the following equation: $$ SA = 2\pi \int_{a}^{b}y\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\hspace{1mm}dx $$ Where y, in this case, is given by: $$ y = \sqrt{5-x} $$ And, as you mentioned in your comment, the derivative with respect to x is given by: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{5-x}} $$We then can substitute these expressions into the equation: $$ SA = 2\pi \int_{3}^{5}\sqrt{5-x}\hspace{0.6mm}\cdot \hspace{0.6mm} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4(5-x)}} \hspace{1mm}dx $$ Since the left term and the right term both have an exponent of ½, and we know that: $$ a^c \cdot b^c=(ab)^c  $$ We can simplfy the integrand to: $$ \sqrt{5-x+\frac{1}{4}}  $$ Which leaves us with the following expression to be integrated:$$ 2\pi \int_{3}^{5} \sqrt{\frac{21}{4}-x} \hspace{1mm}dx $$ Which shouldn't be too difficult of an integral to solve at this point in your calculus studies.

Comment: I have made it to the last step shown but am lost where to go next.

Comment: try making a u sub for the expression in the radical (i.e. u = 21/4 - x)