# Why cannot set up initial tableau?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

> A student is trying to decide on the lowest cost diet that meets the
>   nutrition requirements, with two choices: steak and peanut butter.
>   Steak costs 7 dollars a pound and peanut butter costs 5 dollars a
>   pound. Steak has 2 units of protein per pound and peanut butter has 1
>   unit of protein per pound. A proper diet needs at least 5 units of
>   protein per day. Unfortunately, steak also has 8 units of cholesterol
>   per pound and peanut butter has 4 units of cholesterol per pound. High
>   quantity of cholesterol is bad and the daily limit for cholesterol is
>   10 units. How many pounds of steak and peanut butter should the
>   student consume daily?

Write this LPP in standard form, then convert into canonical form. Why do we not get a initial simplex tableau just using the original decision variables and the slack variables?

---

Let $x_1$ = pounds of steak

Let $x_2$ = pounds of PB

In standard form --

Minimize: $$z=7x_1+5x_2$$

Subject to:

$$2x_1+1x_2 \geq 5$$
$$8x_1+4x_2 \leq 10$$
$$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$$

---

In canonical form --

Minimize: $$z=7x_1+5x_2$$

Subject to:

$$2x_1+1x_2 + s_1 = 5$$
$$8x_1+4x_2 + s_2 = 10$$

### $$x_1, x_2 \geq 0$$

Thus, my main question is **why do we not get a initial simplex tableau just using the original decision variables and the slack variables?**

Well the way I think about it is, that when you draw this graphically, there really is no region of feasibility. Perhaps we need to convert this into a maximization problem before setting up the initial simplex tableau. But what is the actual, mathematical reason behind why we cannot get an initial simplex tableau? How would I explain this to someone?

Comment: You are wrong about $2x_1+x_2+s_1=5$. That gives the inequality the wrong way round. Because $2x_1+x_2\ge5$ you need to have $2x_1+x_2-s_1=5$ but that will not give you an initial simplex tableau because the origin is not in the feasible region. You need to create an artificial variable...

Comment: @tomi You don't need this as this is too slow.  Use the [dual simplex method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998293/290189) instead to solve it in one single stage.  Therefore, the question is *wrong*: we *can* set a an initial simplex tableau and find a feasible solution.